# Proper ODBC Connection string syntax

Tags: web-config, odbc, connection-string

I am trying to build a connection string to and ODBC using an IBM ODBC Driver.

This is what I currently have:

```
<add name="ODBCConnection"
     connectionString="Driver=IBM InfoSphere Classic ODBC Driver V10.1;Server=XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM;Port=XXXX;Database=DTM;"/>
```

When I try to connect to my OdbcCOnnection object, it says the the connection string is wrong. Everything I see online seems to say this is the correct syntax. Any idea what is wrong? The driver name I pulled directly from the ODBC Data Source admin console.

Comment: try adding this to your existing connection string providerName="System.Data.Odbc"

Comment: No luck. I changed the Server part to be Server=myServer,MyPortNumber.  I saw that online, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you workaround it by using "System DSN"?

Comment: You have to put the driver name in {} as it contains spaces i.e., DRIVER={IBM InfoSphere Class Driver V10.1};Server=xxx.